# Password Protected File attached to Email not asking for password

Tags: java, email-attachments

Let me know if you need anymore details as I do not know what I should put to get some help.

So I have a password protected excel file that I send as an email attachment in my code. I password protect the file in the code. The file that gets saved locally asks for the password when I open the file. But when I open the file through the email I sent out it does not ask for a password and just opens right up. I searched online but couldn't find anything.

This is the code where I encript the file and send the email

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poi,true);
workbook.writeProtectWorkbook("pass","");
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(myExcelFile);
```

...

```
Email email = new Email(to, from , subject, body.toString(), true);
email.attachFile(myExcelFile);
email.send();
```

Comment: You need to construct a minimal example and post some code.

Comment: @Lalaland I added the code I'm using to password protect the file and then the code i use to email the file.

Comment: The answer is very simple, the file being sent is not the encrypted file, unless you are specifically decrypting it before sending. Check by generating a hash (before encryption, after encryption and one one after receiving the file)

Comment: @MJSG I do not decrypt it. I'm just trying to set it up so when someone tries to open the file it prompts the user for a password before they can even see the file. I only want the user to have to type in the password, I dont want to have them have any sort of encryption keys or anything of the sort. If i do as you are suggesting will this change the way they will be "decrypting" it? As a preface I'm an entry level developer so I'm sorry if what i'm saying doesnt make sense.

Comment: @fMont As far as I know, an email program does not have the necessary knowledge to decrypt the contents of the attachment. Make sure that you are sending the encrypted contents.

Comment: @MJSG Look at my answer for more details. So to check the password was on there I saved the attachment and opened it from the file explorer and the excel file asked for the password as its supposed to. The problem comes from outlook just ignoring the fact that it needs a password and just opens the file anyways when you double click the attachment from within the outlook email. I decided to by pass this via putting the file into a .zip archive and putting a password on the .zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more testing and asking some coworkers I have found out that email programs don't know how to handle a file that has a simple password on it so it just opens up the file like normal. If you download the attachment and open it up through your file system then it will prompt you for the password, but if you just try to open it directly from the email itself (Outlook, Gmail, etc.) will just ignore the password and open it up.
What I've decided to do is just put the file into a zip archive and just add a password to that. Hopefully the email programs/apps don't ignore it or at least when you try to open the file from the archive it will prompt you for the password because you are no longer opening it from the email itself.

Long story short its the email programs/apps that is causing my problem not my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

After having a similar issue (but using c# to compile and email the Excel file) I protected the worksheet before saving the file instead of protecting the workbook.

When opening the file from an email (or any other way) and attempting to edit a cell a warning is displayed that the sheet is protected and read-only until it is unprotected with the password.